# React Thumbnail Preview when posting/ sharing links of URL

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, thumbnails, preview

I'm trying to get preview of the page from different links within my react project but it's only showing the index.html "home" preview. I understand React is a SPA, but is there a module or a method to display previews/ thumbnails when I'm sharing/ posting these links? I'm using a headless CMS with Wordpress as the backend with API calls. I would like to post preview/ thumbnails of the articles/ etc.. I create.

example:
www.foxnews.com
[image]

Comment: You're asking for a lot here, and it probably ain't gonna be easy :). So is what you are wanting to visit the link, render that page to an image thumbnail, and display that on your page? Or do you want to load the page in an iframe? Or something else? Do you already have the thumbnails available somewhere? Or do you wanna use the [openGraph](https://ogp.me) info to generate the thumbnails? Also, do you have an example of what the final result would look like?

Comment: Here's one possibility: https://github.com/securecoders/opengraph-react

Comment: @GarrettMotzner Thank you for getting back to me on this. I've edited the description with an example. So what it sounds like is I need some where to store thumbnails and a description that are ready to go which something like openGraph would suffice?

Comment: Yeah, based on your example, what you want is something similar to open graph. Open graph works by accessing a link and gathering specific metadata from the html. So then when you visit that link, you can use the metadata to generate a thumbnail, instead of having to render the entire page. Take a look at `opengraph-react` and see if that does what you need.

Comment: @GarrettMotzner Thank you very much! :)

Comment: Give a try at [@microlink/react](https://github.com/microlinkhq/sdk) or [react-tiny-link](https://github.com/winhtaikaung/react-tiny-link/)

Answer (score 3):

there is a file called index.html in the public folder of react app

in there you should add meta property tags like this

```html
<meta property="og:URL" content="%PUBLIC_URL%/localImage.jpg" />

<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
    
<meta property="og:title" content="lorem ipsum lorem ipsum" />
    
<meta property="og:description" content="lorem ipsum" />

<meta property="og:image" content="%PUBLIC_URL%/localImage.jpg" />
```

[image: location of index.html in public folder]

Comment: Would this work for link shares to android users as well as iphone?

Answer (score 0):

i had the same issue , and here is how i solved it

i've added the thumnail in page website
which can be access from the route (you want to give him a thumbnail)
make as **the first element** of your page (or at least your first picture )

*because : the thumbnail link take the first picture of your website*

and then with Css make sure that the picture doesn't appear
but **! WARNING !** don't do that :

```
display : none
```

because it will be as a removed pic and will not be considered

Here is an example of how i did that bellow !

**in .jsx file of your page**

```
<div className="thumbnail">
      <img src="/thumbnails/landing.png" alt=""/>
</div>
```

**here is the style in sass same as in css**

```
.thumbnail
    position : absolute
    top : 0 
    z-index : -5000
    width : 0px
    height : 0px
    img
        object-fit : cover
        width : 0px
        height : 0px
```

Answer (score 0):

to get the feature you need to paste the following markup to your html page in the head tag.

```
<meta property="og:title" content="title" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website">
<meta property="og:description" content="Content description />
<meta property="og:image" content="image you want to show here" />
<meta property="og:url" content="url ">
```